# Missing manager for some users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-service

I am facing an annoying issue with my User Profile Application : some users don't have a manager in SharePoint whereas they have one in Active Directory.

I have run several full / part synchronization, everything works fine but not for everyone.

My Active Directory is divided in several OUs (with country / region for example) but there are all checked in the User Profile Application connection.

When I open FIM and check my user, there is no manager property, but if I open another user, I will have the manager property. I have run a PS script and found that I have more than 500 accounts without managers (for 1600 users)

Any ideas ?

Thank you for your help !

FYI :

- SharePoint 2010
- 3 WFE
- 2 clusters SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several fierce battles : I have deleted and re-created the User Profile Application, without deleting all data, I was able to enter the same Profile and Social databases' names and it kept all data. (http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=300)

Now it works !

Thank you Matthew for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would start troubleshooting this from AD. Do the users in AD (that are failing in SharePoint) have VALID managers? By this I mean are the accounts of the Manager attribute valid AD accounts? (They haven't been deleted or disabled.) Usually, the FIM import exposes issues with AD that you didn't know you had.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately this is the first thing that I have checked : yes, users have valid AD accounts as manager. One weird thing : for example when I update manually one user and fill his manager, when I run another full synchro, it is deleted...

Comment: Are they all in the same domain? FIM appears to think something is amiss. Is there anything common among the missing Managers?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same domain. We have prod / pre-prod plateform with the same configuration, filter and OU selected in User Profile, and it's working in our Pre-prod platform... It's quite annoying and I cannot understand why

Comment: Are the FIM Import logs the same?

Answer (score 0):

When using the User Profile Active Directory Import setting you have to leave the manager mapping in the User Profile Properties blank in order for them to sync. If you map the manager field to an Active Directory attribute SharePoint will not be able to resolve the user. No mapping should exist for the SharePoint manager field and it should sync properly with Active Directory.